# Eclipse Neon: unable to hide min/max button row in split pane editor layout

Tags: css, eclipse, user-interface, swt, eclipse-neon

Getting started with Eclipse Neon.

Pleasantly surprised to see that we can now recapture nearly all wasted space from the UI with little effort.

For example, Gtk 3.20 (on Linux) streamlines scrollbars and gutters to the point where there's no longer a need to create a custom plugin to hide space-wasting elements. To hide *entire* toolbar row, just a click away: Window > Appearance > Hide ToolBar. Bottom status bar? Just define override attribs and import custom css file into target theme a la `@import('custom_gtk.css')`:

```
#org-eclipse-ui-trim-status,
#org-eclipse-ui-trim-vertical2,
#org-eclipse-ui-main-toolbar {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

There is, however, one issue I have been unable to workaround via custom css: in split editor layouts a separate top row appears with min/max buttons. The row serves no purpose since max button is not attached to any editor panel file (i.e. clicking max button does nothing). The end result is 20-30px of wasted vertical space.

[image]

Have tried various override incantations using CSS Spy, but none have worked. Would love to find a solution to this problem as out of the box space preserving VIM-like editing is nearly at hand in Neon.

Here's [E4 Bugzilla tracker issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497605) (generally not much activity there so trying SO in hopes of finding a solution or possible workarounds).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit heavy handed but does the trick. In my eclipse `plugins/org.eclipse.ui.theme.../css` directory I have a `custom_gtk.css` file with, among other overrides, the following:

```
CTabFolder {
  swt-maximize-visible: false;
  swt-minimize-visible: false
}
```

Hides all min/max elements and the extraenous row in which the elements are defined (if editor tabs exist then the row remains, only min/max buttons are hidden).

Comment: On Windows this hides the buttons but the bar is still there. Does it really remove the entire bar for you (on Linux) ? Not sure what you meant be 'editor tabs exist' because they're always going to exist while you're working.

Comment: @AndyBrown yes, the entire bar is gone. Since the problem only manifests in split pane view, by "editor tabs exist" I mean the row containing their labels (Foo.scala, Bar.scala) remains but without the min/max icons. Before the fix an empty bar spanning entire screen width would appear with a useless min/max icons *above* split pane bars containing file tab labels.

Comment: @AndyBrown fwiw, in the past I resorted to writing a custom plugin that hacked Eclipse source code to hide scrollbars, min/max icons, etc. In Neon life is far simpler, at least on Linux at any rate. Good luck, wasted space is not the end of the world but still annoying...